# How do I start reading from a certain row from a txt file in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a `.txt` file with columns that I want to read but there are some rows in the beginning of the file that I dont want to read. **How do I start reading from the actual data and not the string at the beginning of the file itself?** Like for instance if I were interested in data from column "Data C".

*Sample of the `.txt` file:*

```
Image:xxx
Distance:xxx
Wave:xxx
Nbr:xxx
Width:xxx
Distance:xxx
Camera:xxx
Data A  Data B  Data C  Data D  Data E  
-0,025500   NaN 0,000203    NaN 0,092413    
-0,025465   NaN 0,000168    NaN 0,095967
```

---

**Attempt:**

```
filename = 'filename.txt';
delimiterIn = ' ';
headerlinesIn = 8;
A = importdata(filename,delimiterIn,headerlinesIn);
A.data
```

***Output:***

> Dot indexing is not supported for variables of this type.

Answer (score 2):

Since it looks like the data is fixed width (9,6,9,6,9), I would use [**`textscan`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) with `HeaderLines` and then [**`strrep`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html) the commas:

```matlab
fid = fopen('filename.txt');
data = textscan(fid, '%9s%6s%9s%6s%9s', 'HeaderLines', 8, 'CollectOutput', true);
fclose(fid);

A = cellfun(@str2double, strrep(data{1}, ',', '.'))

% A =
%
%    -0.0255       NaN    0.000203     NaN    0.092413
%    -0.025465     NaN    0.000168     NaN    0.095967
```